# Apple wired mouse only scrolls up

Tags: mouse

My Apple wired mouse will either just scroll up but not down, or the opposite. What can I do to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you clarify how long you have had this mouse for? Is it a mechanical issue or do you think that it is a software setting? What steps have you taken to try and get is to work.

Comment: Try another mouse, or try that one in another machine.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with Apple Wired Mice (a.k.a. Mighty Mouse) products. There is no permanent fix, the issue happens when the mouse gets dirt from your fingers building up in the mechanism, and eventually jams.

You can fix it temporarily by following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204172). There is a section "Magic Trackpad, Magic Mouse, Wireless Mighty Mouse, and Apple Wireless Mouse, Wired Apple Mouse, Wired Mighty Mouse", the instructions are in the second paragraph:

> If the scroll ball on your Mighty Mouse has become discolored or
>   dirty, use a clean, lint-free cloth lightly moistened with water to
>   clean it. Wipe the ball and the surrounding area, making sure to
>   rotate the ball itself to ensure complete coverage. If the scrolling
>   feels rough or if the scroll ball isn't scrolling up, down, or
>   side-to-side, hold the Mighty Mouse upside down and roll the ball
>   vigorously while cleaning it to help dislodge any particles that might
>   have collected on the internal hardware. [Watch a QuickTime movie
>   demonstration of this procedure.](https://im.corp.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT3226/HT326.mov) (The movie is approximately 600 KB.)